# Updating JPanel's within a JScrollPane not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I created a `JScrollPane` and want to display a different `JPanel` within that `JScrollPane` depending on input I get from the user.  For some reason, my `JScrollPane` remains blank and never paints what is in the `Panel`.

```
private JScrollPane panelView;

// Creating my ScrollPane with a blank JPanel
panelView = new JScrollPane(new JPanel());
// Scenario1 is my top level JPanel, also contains a JTree
scenario1.add(panelView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

My code when I get the action to update the JPanel displayed. I've confirmed through the debugger that I'm hitting this code properly.

```
// Remove previous displayed JPanel within JScrollPane
panelView.removeAll();
if(node.equals(nodes.loginDefaultUser))
    {
        loginDefaultUserPanel = new LoginDefaultUserPanel();    
        panelView.add(loginDefaultUserPanel);
    }
    else if(node.equals(nodes.addUsers))
    {
        addUsersPanel = new AddUsersPanel();
        panelView.add(addUsersPanel);
    }
    else if(node.equals(nodes.getVersions))
    {
        getVersionsPanel = new GetVersionsPanel();
        panelView.add(getVersionsPanel);
    }
    panelView.revalidate();
    panelView.repaint();
```

Comment: Remove `panelView.removeAll()` and just use `panelView.setViewportView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JScrollPane#setViewportView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29) instead of `add`

You might find reviewing [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) of use

Comment: I've given that a shot, but still the same behavior (sorry having problems with my comment format).

For example:

`if(node.equals(ndes.loginDefaultUser))
  

{
   
loginDefaultUserPanel = new LoginDefaultUserPanel();
   panelView.setViewportView(loginDefaultUserPanel);
   
   //panelView.add(loginDefaultUserPanel);
  }`

Comment: Ah, just figured it out.  Once I replaced the add with setViewportView and then also removed my `panelView.removeAll();` from the beginning of the method` then it worked. I'm not sure why I don't have to remove the previous Panel (or why it was breaking things to begin with), but it looks correct now.

Comment: @Matt You don't need to remove the previous component explicitly because the viewport is designed to only support a single child component, calling `setViewportView` will automatically remove the previous child before adding the new one...Calling `removeAll` will remove all the children from the `JScrollPane` - that includes the `JViewport` - which you DON'T want to do ;)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the explanation and you've been very helpful.